# Alternative to Lambda for Serverless Long running tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using a AWS Step function, where I have a map task. For each item in the input to the map task, plan was to trigger a Lambda function. I had designed the wireframe as such.

But now there has been change in the function code and the new code takes around 1+ hours in CPU and there is also a possibility to run it with GPU support.

Thus, I need to replace Lambda functions with another serverless aws service. Please suggest on which service to use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "serverless" solution to running a task on AWS for more than 15 minutes is to run it as an [ECS task with a Fargate launch type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/AWS_Fargate.html).

[Step Functions can manage ECS Fargate tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-ecs.html)

Comment: Thanks... Correct me If I am wrong .... But Fargate can only lunch max 10 instances ... However I will have more than 10 input to the map task ... also I think Fargate does not support GPU instances ... Although I am Ok with CPU based compute say with 16 or 32 vCPUs ...But will need to handle more than 10 inputs to the Map task ... How do you suggest i go about it ? Thanks.

Comment: You are wrong about the max 10 instances. That may be the default for a new AWS account or something, but you can have many more than 10. You are correct about the current lack of GPU support on Fargate. If you need GPU for machine learning tasks, you could look at [Serverless SageMaker](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/12/amazon-sagemaker-serverless-inference/).

Comment: What about AWS batch?

Comment: @JorgeArimany yes AWS Batch is another option. There are many options on AWS, pick the one that works best for your specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an Autoscaling Group that scales out EC2 machines. This way you can specify an AMI that suits your needs.